# How to order images onto webpage in .net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, slider, web

I'm using a slider where the main picture is shown after the thumbnails are rendered. I'm using jquery which someone else wrote. The thumbnails are rendered on the page but the main image appears only after all the adverts so takes too long.

I was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

consider a direction pointed
[Jquery Image Sliders](http://designmodo.com/jquery-image-sliders/)

I don't know what problem you're having with your advertisements.  Try making them wait until your page finishes loading? [Jquery can tell you this.](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)